# Loading map using a service call

Tags: navigation, ros2, mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am having trouble understanding or creating service calls for loading maps using map_server. This [link](https://index.ros.org/p/nav2_map_server/#:%7E:text=ros2%20service%20call%20/map_server/load_map%20nav2_msgs/srv/LoadMap%20%22%7Bmap_url%3A%20/ros/maps/map.yaml%7D%22) provides idea of how to call it from the terminal. But unable to understand how can I call it from the python node. What should be my import like `nav_msgs.srv` or `map_msgs.srv`.
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398177/loading-map-using-a-service-call/) by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2022-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Updating solution just in case anyone has the same problem.
To import, we have to use.

`from nav2_msgs.srv import LoadMap`

Sample code for the service call

```
Class Service(Node):
    def__init__(self):   
        self.map_client = self.create_client(LoadMap,'/map_server/load_map')
        self.map_request = LoadMap.Request()
        while not self.map_client.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=10.0):
                self.get_logger().info('Waiting for service')

        self.send_request()
    
    def send_request(self):
            self.map_request.map_url = "../maps/my_map.yaml"
            wait = self.map_client.call_async(self.map_request)
            rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, wait)
            if wait.result() is not None:
                self.get_logger().info('Request was responded')
            else:
                self.get_logger().info('Request Failed')
```

This will send map data to `/map` topic that can be used to get the map data

---

Originally posted by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) with karma: 126 on 2022-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0